# Menu in position relative

Tags: html, css

I've this code

```css
.bloc {
    width: 40%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align:center
}

.bloc ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
<a href="#">A link</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

I want the `ul` be outside the div `.bloc` and the div `.bloc` adapt its height.

I try to `position relative` it but the height of `.bloc` don't adjust with the first link

I hope I'm explicit.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Why don't you just put _ul_ outside _.block_ with HTML? And after that just write css like in _.block_. Is it what you want? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lends/9otut1c3/)

Comment: My assumption would be that he has limited control over the html and can only manipulate it with css. He said below it is not possible to put the ul outside in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-top: 15px;` instead of `top: 15px;` on the `ul`

```css
.bloc {
    width: 40%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align:center
}

.bloc ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
<a href="#">A link</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: I want the ul to be outside the div 'bloc', not inside. The 'ul' has to be center like the first link too

Comment: By the way in my case, put the ul outside the div in the HTML is not possible

Answer (score 0):

To make the UL appear outside of `.bloc` you could add `transform: translateX(100%)` to your `.bloc ul` rule. That will shift the UL 100% (relative to the UL's width) to the right on the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bloc ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top: 15px;
 }
```

is working for me, I've just tested it. By the way what you're creating isn't the best way to make the navbar since it will collapse as you close the page position relative. Instead the ul would be better with:

```
 float:right;
 display:block;
 position:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the parent position: relative; and the child position: absolute; then you can force the child to have the same width, but push it outside the div without affecting its displayed size.

```css
.bloc {
    width: 40%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

.bloc > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
<a href="#">A link</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
</ul>    
</div>
```